# Transculent screen on top of another in React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

In my app, I have two screens, `home` and `search`. I have to show `search` on top of `home`. The background of `search` will be the blurred image of whatever is on `home`. I have tried using `react-navigation` method `push` to ddo this. But it is not working. How do I do this?

```
this.props.navigation.push('search');
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood well, you need to use Modals. You have the basic documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal). But i recommend you to use the [react-native-modals](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) library. Hope it works.

Comment: Modals for whole screens is a pain to code and use. I would rather not use them. Can you make the background of modals translucent?

Comment: With react-native-modals it's a little bit easier. For transparent background only use, for example, backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)'